# parse a json array inside a json array in php

Tags: php, json

I am having a json object `$result`

I do this:

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);
```

Here is the output if I use this:

`var_dump($json)`

is this:

```
array(15) { ["id"]=> int(1)  ["name"]=> array(16) { ... } }
```

If I do this:

```
echo $json['id'];
echo $json['name'];
```

The id is printed correctly : 1
But in the name this is printed: **Array**

How can I get that array and print it?

Comment: You haven't shown enough of the object. What do you get if you do this? `var_dump($json['name'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways:

```
print_r($json['name']);
var_dump($json['name']);
```

Or manual with preferred delimiter:

```
echo implode(", ", $json['name']);
```

However you should check the function responsible for making that JSON string, because you expect a `string` instead of `array`.